# Get product version from a custom action

Tags: c#, wix

I have a Wix installer.
In the Product.wxs file, I have the below piece of code:

```cs
<Product Id="*"
    Name="$(var.PRODUCT_NAME)"
    Language="1033"
    Version="!(bind.FileVersion.myDLLfile)"
    Manufacturer="$(var.CompanyName)"
    UpgradeCode="{D00BA432-7798-588A-34DF-34A65378FD45}">
```

In the Features.wxs, I have the myDLLfile defined as component:

```cs
<Component Id="myDLLfile"
    Guid="{30550881-053F-768D-88B7-BB9853B23C51}">
    <File Id="myDLLfile"
        Source="$(var.dllDir)\myDLLfile.dll"
        KeyPath="yes"
        Checksum="yes"/>
</Component>
```

Now, I would like to know if from a custom action in C# I can get that same Product Version (which corresponds to the version of the myDllfile.dll). Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: The answer is yes.  Both files are xml file an using an xml library you can match the version.  I would need to see more of the two xml files.

Comment: @jdweng I am not refering to get the file version of Product.wxs and Features.wxs files, instead i am referring to get the Version field value of Version="!(bind.FileVersion.myDLLfile)"

Comment: I know you are referring to to the element names inside the xml file.

Comment: @jdweng ok, just wanted to ensure that both understand each other and there is no misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to store the value in a `Property` and read that property in the custom action. The bind variable syntax would make setting the property easy.

```xml
   <Property Id="ThisIsASillyThingToNeedToDo" Value="!(bind.FileVersion.myDLLfile)" />
```